# Angular UI-Router - using "resolve" directly on template url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui, state

I am using UI-Router and want to change routing to be 'component based'. So Instead of defining a controller / template I want to use it like this:

```
.state('issue', {
    url: '/someUrl/:number',
    template: '<my-directive></my-directive>',
    resolve: {
      data: function(dataService) {
        return dataService.getData().then(function(response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            return response.data;
        });
      }
    }
 })
```

Now, I know that with Angular's `ngRoute` I can use resolved data directly in the template, for example:

```
 $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        template: `<my-directive data="resolve.data"></my-directive>`,
        resolve: {
          data: function (dataService) {
            return dataService.getData();
          }
        }
      })
```

I couldn't do it using UI-Router (value was undefined).

Am I doing something wrong? Is it possible using ui-router?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point with `UI-Router` is - result of `resolve` is available for a **`controller`** *(related to template)*. So, we could do it like this:

```
.state('issue', {
    url: '/someUrl/:number',
    template: '<my-directive data="stateCtrlData"></my-directive>',
    controller: function($scope, data) { $scope.stateCtrlData = data },
    resolve: {
      data: function(dataService) {
        return dataService.getData().then(function(response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            return response.data;
        });
      }
    }
  })
```

The `data` are passed into controller and from its scope we pass it to directive.

Comment: Great if that helped anyhow ;) Enjoy mighty UI-Router

Answer (score 0):

If you mean injecting your data service, then you can do it like this (remember that the '' is telling to inject):

```
state('issue', {
        url: '/someUrl/',
        template: '<my-directive data="pep.data"></my-directive>',
        controller: function( data) { this.data = data },
        controllerAs: 'pep',  
        resolve:{
                 dataSvc : 'YourDataSvc',
                 campaign : function(dataSvc){
                         return dataSvc.getData();

                }
             }
```

Please remember a `ui-view` will be expected if you want to put additional views or child states.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can (tested only in ui-router v0.3.2)

There's an *undocumented* $resolve variable which is automatically injected in the controller.
Simply add 'controllerAs' property to the state as follows, and you can use $resolve in the template:

```
.state('issue', {
    url: '/someUrl/:number',
    template: '<my-directive data="vm.$resolve.data"></my-directive>',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    resolve: {
      data: function(dataService) {
        return dataService.getData().then(function(response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            return response.data;
        });
      }
    }
 })
```